# .htaccess mod_rewrite friendly url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the php file `page.php`.
URLS:

1. `page.php?content=contact`
2. `page.php?content=aboutus`

I need it to be shown like this:

1. `mysite.com/contact`
2. `mysite.com/aboutus`

I figured out that I have to make `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^paginas/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?page=contact [L]
```

Tryed many things.. No results..
Thanks for attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(?:GET|HEAD)\ /+page\.php\?content=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /page.php?content=$1 [L]
```

This will first redirect: `/page.php?content=anything` to `/anything` then internally rewrite *back* requests like `/anything` to `/page.php?content=anything`.